# UIImage how to resize bubble image with capInsets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have bubble like image, that I need to resize dynamically.
Example attached.
I will have dynamic text and I need to resize only straight parts of bubble. Leave down arrow on the middle
How can I do this?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117787/custom-resizable-image-drawing-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

I think that `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` will be pretty useful for you

Example:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0,10.0,5.0,10.0)];
[self.yourButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I wrote example with button because it's a common case of using this method. Just play with caps values.

HTH!

**EDIT:**

Thought about this problem and wrote small example.
I understood that `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` can save only corners of image in case we use two dimension scale.

I see 2 ways:

1. Use two controls: one for balloon and one for arrow with proper images
2. Render image for this one control from two images

I decided to realize second one.
Pass ballonView.frame as argument here:

```
- (UIImage *)balloonImageWithRect:(CGRect)rect{
    //create two images, ballon image with cap corners
    UIImage *ballonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(IMAGE_CAP_INSET_TOP, IMAGE_CAP_INSET_LEFT, IMAGE_CAP_INSET_BOTTOM, IMAGE_CAP_INSET_RIGHT) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"];

    //drawing area
    CGSize newSize = rect.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

    //leave some space for arrow at the bottom
    [ballonImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height - arrowImage.size.height)];
    //draw arrow at the bottom
    [arrowImage drawInRect:CGRectMake((newSize.width - arrowImage.size.width)/2, newSize.height - arrowImage.size.height, arrowImage.size.width, arrowImage.size.height)];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Then we just set this image to our ballonView.

Also I leave gist with full code of that ViewController with random sizes of that balloon: https://gist.github.com/AlloyDev/7910637

Also you can use that two images:

[image: balloon image]
[image: arrow image]

Comment: It resize, But I can not resize only left and right parts and no to change arrow in the middle

Comment: @Anton you have to cover your arrow under cap, increase your bottom cap value.

Comment: @Anton also this tutorial may be useful for you http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, but with no luck, something I am doing wrong

Comment: @Anton thanks for my curiosity, I tried it by myself. Looks like everything works. Check out my edit and gist with code of my investigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use method:

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight;
```

call like this:

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleImageName.png"]
                       stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:13];
```

Change capWidth and capHeight values

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIImage.h` delegate method

// use resizableImageWithCapInsets: and capInsets.

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight;
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger leftCapWidth;   // default is 0. if non-zero, horiz. stretchable. right cap is calculated as width - leftCapWidth - 1
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSInteger topCapHeight;   // default is 0. if non-zero, vert. stretchable. bottom cap is calculated as height - topCapWidth - 1
```

like this

```
UIImage *balloon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15];
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the image in the question (assuming it's a Retina image):

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bubble"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(14, 28, 14, 26) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

If the image you've provided in the question is a non-retina image, halve the values.

Modify the values (`UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)`) to suit any image you need.