# android resize bubble image with capinsets

Tags: android, ios, imageview

I have experience in iOS development and recently started working on android development too.

In iOS I did an implementation of `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` in order to resize the `UIImage` without altering the boundaries of image. The image is stretched from the inside only.

See this solution for iOS: [UIImage how to resize bubble image with capInsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494660/uiimage-how-to-resize-bubble-image-with-capinsets)

Is there anything similar in android? I want to use the same image file as I used in my iOS app and resize/stretch it from the inside only.

Comment: Look into the `scaletype` attribute of widget `ImageView`: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: which scaletype should i select?

Comment: Try `ScaleType.FIT_XY`.

Comment: Search for `nine patch drawables android`. Seems like that's what you need. These drawables let you define areas along their width and height that will be stretched in case of resizing.

Comment: nine patch worked. I created images here: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html and it worked. If you can write an answer, I will accept it